# twitter application login always asks for permission

Tags: twitter, laravel-4, php-5.4

I'm using the `artdarek package` to implement the **login** process in my web application.
I get a weird behavior by using the twitter login buton action; The application always asks for permission, although the user have accepted it already. Does twitter applications asks for the permission every time we want to login using twitter?
I want to mention that I activated the **read,write permission** in the settings of my twitter apps.
The action of the twitter login is:

```
public function loginWithTwitter() {


// get data from input
$token = Input::get( 'oauth_token' );
$verify = Input::get( 'oauth_verifier' );

// get twitter service
$tw = OAuth::consumer( 'Twitter' );

// check if code is valid

// if code is provided get user data and sign in
if ( !empty( $token  ) && !empty( $verify  ) ) {
    // This was a callback request from twitter, get the token
    $token = $tw->requestAccessToken( $token, $verify );

    // Send a request with it
    $result = json_decode( $tw->request( 'account/verify_credentials.json' ), true );
// return $result['source'];
  //  $message = 'Your unique Twitter user id is: ' . $result['id'] . ' and your name is ' . $result['name'];
    //echo $message. "<br/>";

    //Var_dump
    //display whole array().
         dd($result);

             //   var_dump($result);
                return Redirect::route('login');
            }

        }


// if not ask for permission first
else {
    // get request token
    $reqToken = $tw->requestRequestToken();

    // get Authorization Uri sending the request token
    $url = $tw->getAuthorizationUri(array('oauth_token' => $reqToken->getRequestToken()));

    // return to twitter login url
    return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
}


        }
```

Is there any way to check wether the application was already enabled in twitter so that user will not pass by the permission window every time he login using twitter?

Comment: I have the same thing happening, also using artdarek. Will post here if I find out more, hopefully someone has some insight.